# How to do 360 Polar Panorama in Photography?

Tags: panorama, art, 360-panorama, trick-photography

I Have here a 360 Panorama picture from random Web search:

[image]

I want to ask how to do this, do I need some special lens or any equipment to do this?  It's kind a tricky I guess.

Comment: wow. amazing photograph, i've read an article in a magazine on how to do it. i'll post it later when I find it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some links to tutorials help you get started:

[Digitial Camera world Photoshop tutorial](http://www.digitalcameraworld.com/2012/11/01/polar-panoramas-shoot-and-stitch-360-degree-pictures/)

[Photo extremist tutorial](http://photoextremist.com/how-to-take-360x180-degree-stereographic-planet-panoramas)

[Photojojo tutorial](http://content.photojojo.com/tutorials/create-your-own-panorama-planets/)

This is entirely a product of post processing and stitching multiple exposures together. Not the by-product of some interesting lens. You will need a tripod and the right software (photoshop/some other plugins assist (see articles))

Hope that helps!