# When to use what panorama projection?

Tags: post-processing, panorama, pano-projections

I just counted the number of [projections available in PtAssembler](http://www.tawbaware.com/projections.htm) and came up with 25. Some of those 25 are probably just there just to say that it's there and are not actually useful. Plus, there are probably a bunch that are so close to each other that in the real world it doesn't matter which one you use.

So let's say that there are ~10 usefully different projections. a) which ones are they? b) in what circumstances is one clearly better to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PTAssembler link below explains a lot about those projections.  It specifically answers the question you asked ... Why use the different projects?

http://www.tawbaware.com/projections.htm

Actually, as you'll see, PTAssembler has those variations so that you can get the control you want.   Think of it as, what a DSLR is to a Point-and-Shoot.

Max Lyons added many of those variants when he wrote some of his code to replace some of Dersch's PanoTools.  I use the Squeezed and Compressed Rectilinear variants for good effect.

V/R

B. Shaw

Comment: D'oh! How did I miss that???

Comment: Andy - Don't feel bad,  I think I may have originally found that page by 'googling' projections and PTAssembler.

Answer (score 1):

Which projections are useful to you depends a lot on what type of panoramas you're making, the image itself, and how you want to present the pano.  That list is pretty standard for any [Panorama Tools](http://panotools.sourceforge.net)-based GUI (that's where the PT in PTGui, PTAssembler, PTLens, etc. comes from).

I'd say take a spin through [this Hugin manual page on projections](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/Projections.html) to get a visual sense of what each of them does. It's typically about emphasizing or de-emphasizing areas of the resulting panorama, because of the distortion that's required to map the larger angles of view or a spherical field to a flat plane.

As a 360°x180° panorama shooter, my needs are probably quite different from yours, but I tend to use **equirectangular** as the final stitching format, because it can encompass a spherical view (as cylindrical cannot), and [**stereographic** for little planet remapping](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23760/how-are-mini-planet-photos-created/49621#49621).

Comment: Inkista - Actually, PTAssempler has grown in the past couple of years.  It is no longer merely a front end to Dersch's PanoTools.  Max Lyons wrote his own code which added a significant amount of projections.

Comment: Cool. I'm not that familiar with PTAssembler--just knew that I'd seen a lot of the same projections in the other PT-whatever tools. There was a lot that Dersch kept proprietary, and I do get mixed up about which codebase is from where. :)

Answer (score 0):

No panorama projection is usefull unless you need it.

**So my question is, What do you need the panorama for?**

I use some panoramas as:

#### 1) Just interesting pictures.

- Spherical
- Planar (Spherical Probe)
- Cylindrical
- Little planet

#### 2) Viewing an interior scene or landscape on a web aplication, or desktop aplication, virtual tours.

- Spherical
- Cubical. 6 independent images.

#### 3) Environmental maps in 3D rendering aplications.

- Spherical
- Hemispherical
- Cylindrical
- Planar (Spherical Probe)
- Cubical
- Vertical Cross, Horizontal cross.

Here is a paper I wrote some time ago as an explanation to a 3D modeling comunity, to understand a little more about the projections.

http://www.otake.com.mx/Apuntes/Imagen/EnviromentMaps/

I don't use some projections like mercator. In my opinion this are used to see the exterior projection of a sphere. A panorama is the view from the inside. The projections can be the same but the aplications probably don't.

And there other projections that I don't use as panoramas like rectilinear projection, but as normal photos.