# I want to make a 360 degree photo in one static photo

Tags: photoshop, camera-settings, 360-panorama

How can I make a photo like this using my Smart Phone camera and Photoshop?
[image: 360 degree image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are "Little Planet" photos created?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23760/how-are-little-planet-photos-created)

Comment: related: [How are virtual tour photos taken?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8129/how-are-virtual-tour-photos-taken)

Answer (score 1):

I think Szulat is not wrong when giving an suggestion to use a sphere. That is a perfectly valid suggestion. If you examine the example posted by user7677025, there is also a reflection of the lens, and it reveals the shot is indeed made by using a sphere reflection.

The only problem is that you then need something like a clean glass or plastic tube where the sphere is attached to the other end of it. Otherwise you also get the reflection of the stick or hand or what ever you use to hold the sphere on front of the scene.

But to get a good sphere reflection, it is probably better to shoot it further away, and then crop the image. Otherwise the reflection of the camera itself will look way too big in the image because usually smart phone cameras comes with a wide angle lens. Then to get a good cropped image requires a smart phone with lots of megapixels to get at least adequate results.

**Another option** is to use the smart phone camera's "stitch panorama feature", if there is one available. On many new smart phones there are pretty good software that does rather good quality panorama by stitching multiple shots into one.  Then shoot a 360 panorama, or as "long" panorama as possible.  Or use just any good landscape shot.

**Next on PhotoShop** (or GIMP) you can create so called "tiny planet" image by following e.g. this tutorial: [Photoshop Cs5 Tutorial: The Tiny Planet Photo Effect by Justin Odisho](https://youtu.be/oQbC_Geuwao)

I will not go onto all shooting and editing details here, unless someone asks me to do so. But for example I do recommend trying to use a tripod, and attach the mobile phone onto it with a clamp if it is a stitched panorama you are shooting. And try to shoot something where's no much stuff and details on the foreground.

See also the links to similar topics on the right margin, for example to find out more about "little planet" post processing.

Comment: Also do check this out to get a 360 panorama image taken with your smart phone: [Google Street View app] (https://www.google.com/streetview/apps/).

Answer (score -2):

Take a photo of a reflecting sphere. Depending on the surface quality you might get a marginally usable, low resolution 360 panorama.
For a horizontal 360 view, place your camera (phone) directly above or directly below the sphere.

[image: "Hand with Reflecting Sphere" by Joseph Choi. Licensed under CC BY 2.0]

Comment: This will only ever provide half the image.

Comment: @MrPablo actually far more than half (see [Paul Debevec's page on lightprobes for HDR/CGI](http://www.pauldebevec.com/Probes/)), but it's not how the OP's image was made. The problem with the silver sphere thing is that you're reliant on the quality of the surface of the sphere for the quality of the image, you are not quite getting 360º (missing the point directly opposite the camera) unless you take two images at 90º angles and use masks, and the camera's reflection in the sphere.

Comment: Wouldn't a cone do a better Job here?