# What software should I use to view a photo like this?

Tags: panorama, 360-panorama

Should I use some specific software/app to open it? I have tried panorama / spherical viewers but failed to open the picture properly.

Here is the photo:

[image]

This is what I expect:

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/gC_Tilz3dHo

Comment: Could you perhaps describe by what you mean with "properly"? Because to me this looks like a proper "tiny planet" panorama and it is already knits "proper" form.

Comment: I found a youtube video. Thanks for asking. @SaaruLindestøkke

Answer (score 3):

This is not a working solution, but perhaps it can guide you to something that solves your problem.

I found a Github repository with a javascript library that enables the interactive viewing of panorama's and little planets: [ondras/little-planet](https://github.com/ondras/little-planet)

[This page](https://ondras.github.io/little-planet/showcase.html) has a demonstration of its capabilities.

I tried it out with your image using the HTML snippet below:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/little-planet"></script>
        <little-planet src="photose.jpg" width="200" height="200"></little-planet>
    </body>
</html>
```

I served the HTML snippet using Python's built-in webserver: `python -m http.server`.

Unfortunately it didn't work. The result was a grainy, distorted version of your photo where I could navigate, but in a very disoriented fashion.

Then I found the [source images](https://github.com/ondras/little-planet/tree/main/docs/img) of the demonstration page I linked to earlier. As you can see, all these images are a wide panorama.
I am not sure if you can re-create a wide panorama from your "little planet" type photo, but perhaps you can look at the [steps to create a little planet](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/23760/9161) and reverse those?

Answer (score 1):

[A little planet](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23760/how-are-little-planet-photos-created) still is **not** a 360x180 full spherical panorama or a 360 video.  It's a mapping of a spherical pano, and can be part of one of those interactive videos (entire 360 videos can be mapped that way all the way through), but you need the full panorama with *all* the data to create that type of interactive video. Most typically, an [equirectangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) mapping if you're working with stills.  And then you use something like krpano or [Kuula](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rA6DaW5kiq4) to create the interactive movie with the little planet poster frame.