# How to convert Ricoh Theta equirectangular pictures to rectilinear?

Tags: 360-panorama, ricoh, projection

I would like to extract a portion of an equirectangular 360x180 panorama taken with a Theta S and convert it to what I think is a rectilinear image (a picture where straight lines are shown as such regardless of the lines' direction). Could you please advise on how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @StephenG broken link - 404 error

Comment: Trying again with the link to [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: You can use [libgnomonic by Foxel SA](https://github.com/FoxelSA/libgnomonic/wiki/Equirectangular-to-rectilinear-projection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to remap the panorama. An open source tool for doing this is the [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net) application. A commercial Photoshop plugin for doing this is Flaming Pear's [Flexify](http://www.flamingpear.com/flexify-2.html); a commercial panostitcher you can use is [PTGui](http://www.ptgui.com).

You basically just have to feed the software the equirectangular, and then choose a Rectilinear projection. (See also: [How to reproject and crop a 360°x180° panorama?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/67566/how-to-reproject-and-crop-a-360x180-panorama) for step-by-step instructions with Hugin; the steps are similar for PTGui.) You'll probably need to adjust yaw/pitch/roll to the portion of the scene you want, as well as the FoV. Be aware that you'll have to use a much smaller FoV than 360, because a rectilinear projection is closer to a 90º FoV. Going larger will mean a lot of smearing and stretching at the edges.