# Hugin 360 problems

Tags: panorama, 360-panorama, hugin

I'm new to Hugin. I've been having problems with stitching a 360 panorama together. Could you please help me with what am i doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE! Before we can attempt to help you figuring out what you're doing wrong, we would need to do what you're doing. Can you edit your question to tell a little bit of what it is you're doing? [This link](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) has some information on asking a good question.

Comment: Specifically, we have no idea what the end result is supposed to look like. What are the source images used in the stitch? Obviously there's some sort of problem happening when the triangle-shaped thing just sort of fades, but what is the object **pre-stitch**?

Comment: Since it's indoors you can have parallax problems. Did you set the rotation axis on the entrace pupil of the lens?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like you missed covering the entire scene, and enblend is attempting to blend the black (uncovered) area of the scene with the bits it does have. I would suggest checking that you've cropped member images (if you're using a circular fisheye lens), that you've got enough overlap to cover everything (you want about 1/3 of the frames to overlap in every direction), and that you've applied [masks](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/Blend-masks/en.shtml) correctly.

See also: [What are the best techniques to take 360° panoramas?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/495/what-are-the-best-techniques-to-take-360-panoramas)