# Best settings for photographing 200 paintings indoors with floodlights and a tripod

Tags: raw, aperture, iso, shutter-speed, panasonic-lumix

I want to photograph about 200 acrylic paintings done by a family member who now has dementia.  It's meant to be a tribute in the form of a self-published book.  She had painted as a hobby her entire life and had won multiple awards over the years, and had some paintings on display in the City Hall at one point.

I bought a Panasonic Lumix DMC-LX10 for this purpose. I have two floodlights that are about 5300 K.

I was following the setup and settings in "How to Photograph Artwork, Step by Step" on the Artists Network website, but the images are black:

Manual mode.  RAW format. ISO 125 (lowest it can go), f8, 16000 shutter speed (fastest it can go).

I interpreted this from the guide to mean that I should set the fastest shutter speed possible (but still not clear on how everything links):

> The shutter opens for a fraction of a second. The shutter speed is usually expressed as numbers such as 8, 15, 30, 60, 125, 500 and 1000. In this system, 60 means one-sixtieth of a second and 1000 means one-one-thousandth of a second. The faster the shutter speed, the better you’ll be able to freeze motion. If the camera isn’t on a tripod, don’t use a shutter speed below 60, or the motion of your body will result in blurry photos. Even with a tripod, don’t go below 30.

On (Intelligent) Auto the pictures come out fine, and the camera sets itself at 400 ISO, f2.8, and says "125" which might be the shutter speed, but I'm not sure.

Am I missing something or misunderstanding something?

UPDATE: In "P" or Program mode, the camera sets the aperture and shutter speed automatically.  At 125 ISO it used f2.8 and a shutter speed of 1/30.

In "A" or Aperture-Priority mode, the camera sets the shutter speed automatically given an aperture setting.  At 125 ISO and f8 it used a shutter speed of 1/4.

Comment: What makes you think f8 at 1/16000 of a second shutter speed is correct? Shooting manual doesn't mean any setting is right? Assuming you are using a tripod (you should), I don't see why you would pick a shutter speed faster than say 1/60 of a second.

Comment: From the guide I was reading my understanding was that "faster is better" but it did not explain why or how to make such a judgement or calculation.

Comment: If the guide you were reading really says that "faster is better" (particularly for this kind of shot), it's trash. Throw it away. Not joking.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I included the quote from the guide.  My interpretation, wrongly I now suppose, was that faster was better.

Comment: "The faster the shutter speed, the better you’ll be able to freeze motion." This does not mean *always use the fastest shutter speed the camera is capable of using*. It means *use the fastest shutter speed you can get away with and still have proper exposure.* But it's also assuming you are either hand holding the camera or shooting a moving subject. With a tripod mounted camera and a stationary subject, though, motion blur will not be affected by the shutter speed.

Comment: "The faster the shutter speed, the better you’ll be able to freeze motion." This is theoretically correct, however... the paintings are not moving.

Comment: The issue with the black photos is caused by the incorrect exposure as others noted. However, this site has multiple previous questions on the same topic, it might be helpful to give them a look: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/9531/9161, https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/27949/9161, https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/43401/9161, https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/15612/9161. Good luck!

Comment: @MichaelC It's on a tripod.  I included that info in the title.

Comment: @E2R0NS Oooops!

Comment: @osullic In this case these paintings are not moving, but the quote from the book knows nothing about these paintings nor about the tripod being used. It seems to be making the assumption that either the subject, the camera, or both are possibly moving. Thus, the last sentence in my above comment: "With a tripod mounted camera and a stationary subject, though, motion blur will not be affected by the shutter speed."

Comment: Not to mention that even when the subject is stationary and the camera is on a tripod, such long exposure times can lead to blur if the shutter is operated directly on the camera. Also, at exposure times between about 1/100 and 1 second the movement of the mechanical shutter curtains themselves, or even a mirror in DSLRs, can cause vibrations that lead to blur. (Yes, I'm aware the Panasonic Lumix DMC-LX10 has no mirror and apparently has no mechanical shutter, but others who find this question may be using a camera that does).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things to unpick here:

1. Why were your pictures black? The short answer is "because you didn't let enough light in", the long answer is very well covered in "[what is the exposure triangle?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/what-is-the-exposure-triangle)"
2. Have you misinterpreted your guide? Yes - what it is saying is that a faster shutter speed is better **if your subject is moving** as it prevents blur. If your subject isn't moving, there's no blur to prevent and you can choose your shutter speed more freely, allowing you to get enough light into the camera.

Comment: **If your subject or camera is moving** might be better. Likewise: "If your subject or camera isn't moving..."

Answer (score 3):

I did a similar project so here are my suggestions.

1. Pick the base ISO of the camera. Generally around 100 to 200. If you don't have good lighting this will probably need to be raised, but I wouldn't go above 400.
2. Pick an aperture of around f5.6. If lighting is marginal, you can pick a lower number, but most lenses work well at f5.6.
3. Pick whatever shutter speed is correct for exposure. If you use aperture priority mode, the camera will do this automatically. If you get an exposure you like, you might want to use manual mode to fix the aperture and shutter speed for the rest of the images.
4. Take one image with a [Kodak Gray Card](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/27715-REG/Kodak_1903061_Gray_Cards.html) or its equivalent in the middle of the image. This will help determine exposure and color correction later on.
5. Use a tripod. Really. For every exposure. A remote shutter release is also a good idea.

Comment: Kodak gray card is a reliable option, but far from the most cost-effective one. I like to use a QPcard and there are other good options available too

Comment: To be pedantic, the gray side of the gray card will help with exposure.  The white side will help with setting the white balance.  But as per osullic, nowadays there are better things than simple gray cards

Comment: The gray cards are sold out.  Is there an alternative?

Comment: It's on a tripod leveled with the center of the painting.

Comment: #3 How do I know if it's an exposure I like?  After I take the pics in RAW I thought I should hire someone to process them correctly for the book.  What's best do you think?

Comment: @E2R0NS Getting a good exposure is tricky. Basically you want to avoid any pixels that are completely black or white. What I'm trying to say is take a picture and ask yourself if it looks decent on the camera's screen. Even better is looking at the picture on a computer. The issue there is that, unless you have a calibrated screen, getting color matching between the computer screen and the printed book image is hard. That is a whole different question. If you hire an expert to process the images that should help assuming they are competent but it could get expensive.

Comment: @E2R0NS I used a Kodak Gray card because I had one. As osullic suggests in his comment, there are alternatives that are probably cheaper.

Comment: @PeterM I used a Kodak gray card because I had one. Also they are white on the other side so you can use both sides. I haven't looked into alternatives but I'm sure there are good ones.

Comment: ISO 125 (lowest).  Used Aperture-Priority mode.  Used f4, f5.6, and f8.  Shutter speeds were reported as 20 and lower, so like 1/5, 1/8, 1/20.  Also tried ISO 200 and Aperture-Priority mode.  Got to 1/30 on either f4, f5.6, or f8.  My understanding is that I should the denominator, 30, is the absolute minimum I should strive for.  So 1/60, for example, would be better.

Comment: I will look at the images later tonight in Lightroom (first time using it).

Comment: While taking pics the display showed that there was some handshake even though the camera is on a tripod.  So I turned on the Stabilizer.

Comment: @E2R0NS That generally is not a good idea. Better would be to use the self timer so that the camera can steady itself after you press the shutter release before it takes the shot.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat not the question asked, but well...

Two things that are important, and you have better make a few test shots and check them before doing the full series:

#### Even lighting

You need to have an even lighting over you paintings. Lighting follows a square law, a part of your subject which is 20% farther from the source receives 45% less light. So your light sources have to be sufficiently far away to make these difference negligible.

#### Geometry

Ideally your camera lens should be exactly perpendicular to the painting. If it is not the painting won't be rectangular. This can be corrected later but you can also take a proper shot. If the painting is vertical on a wall, you can

- measure the height of the center of the painting, set the same height for your lens axis,
- make a line on the floor which is perpendicular to the wall, and goes through the center of the painting and put your camera over it
- aim at the center of the painting.

There is also the mirror trick:

- Find a small flat mirror and apply it on the center of the painting (an assistant can be necessary).
- Aim the camera at it, and  move the camera until the reflection of the camera is centered in your viewfinder.
- Remove the mirror before the shot.

Comment: Given that the OP wants to image 300 paintings and then self publish, I'd be tempted to invest in something like a [zig align](http://www.zig-align.com), which seems to be a step up from a simple mirror.  I've thought about getting one for my own tasks of capturing paintings, but the mirror trick works for me right now.

Comment: One thing I'd add, is that if the painting is hung on a wall, depending on how it is hung it may not be vertical even if the wall is.  A local professional I know whose offerings include digitizing artwork (in a town that is a high-end art destination in itself) uses what is effectively a gigantic copy stand with a 4' x 6' table that is known to be perpendicular to the 8' vertical camera rail

Comment: Lighting.  The camera is 42" from the painting.  The light sources are 42" behind the camera (so 84" to the painting)  but 42" to the sides of the camera.  The goal was to direct the lights at 45 degrees to the painting.

Comment: Lighting cont'd.  45 degrees I thought was optimal as per the guide, but on closer reading it appears as though the lights should instead be situated in line with the camera so that the lights and camera are colinear.  I will try that today.

Comment: @PeterM My plan was to capture the pictures in RAW and then hire someone to prepare the book who has experience in publishing artwork/photography.  But perhaps this should not be the same person?  Perhaps I should hire someone to convert the RAW images to some other format for publication?  First timer here.

Comment: You camera must be as far away as possible (without pushing the lens to its limits). Put your lights there on the side of the lens (or slightly in front). Given that you have a tripod, intensity of light is not really important since you can use long exposures, as long as it is brighter enough than than natural lighting that could interfere.

Comment: "so that the lights and camera are colinear" No, please don't. Keep them at an angle.
And the photographing process is more important than RAW conversion. If the first is done right, you barely need the second.

Comment: @Rafael I just meant that the lighting sources are colinear; not that the lights are pointing in the same direction as the camera.  They're not.  They are pointed at the center of the painting and at the same height as the center of the painting.

Comment: Point the center of the left light near the right edge of the painting. Point the right light near the left edge of the painting. This will help average out any hotspots your lights may have.

Comment: @xenoid By long exposure do you mean a shutter speed of 1/5 versus something faster like 1/60?

Comment: 1/5" is fine, with a good tripod. Given your camera you don't have to worry about "mirror slap".