# Remove gradient in Lightroom with source image

Tags: lightroom, lighting, batch, background

I have a series of images (many, many images) that were taken with slightly uneven lighting:

[image]

I also have an image of the blank white background under the same lighting:

[image]

I would like to use the blank image as a map to even out all the other images' background. I know this is commonly done in book scanning and this [great post](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/60001/75330) shows how to do it in Photoshop with layers.

But my images are RAW and I'd like to batch process without saving a ton of intermediate versions. Is it possible to do this in Lightroom?

Comment: Important question: Is the framing and lighting highly consistent between all images you want to run in a single batch, or is was the camera often moved from frame to frame?

Comment: @TheLuckless – yes, the setup is exactly the same for all the images.

Answer (score 1):

Lightroom is a tool for graphical interaction with images rather than batch processing. For your use case Imagemagick looks better suited. There is also a tutorial for this: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#divide

Comment: Yeah, I have used ImageMagick a lot. I've found Lightroom to be great for batch processing (for example, copy/paste develop settings) and had hoped to do it in one, non-destructive step (which might just not be possible).

Answer (score 1):

I use the graduated nd filter in the Color Efex pro 4.0 plugin.   It is easy to adjust.   When you save the image, the setting will be retained in lightroom or PS's filter memory until you change it again.  So, just apply it to every frame.

Comment: Thanks – was hoping for a non-paid solution but this is a good option if I need it.