# How can I best use two torches (aka flashlights) to take photographs of my artwork indoors?

Tags: image-quality, low-light, light, reproduction

I have two lights in my room but their light is not enough. So, I count them as ambient light.

I don't have enough money to buy something expensive like studio stuff, but I have two torches similar to [this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31A6aV1fFHL.jpg). I need to click photo of my artwork, which either I can fix on wall or place on a table.

I know I can place the lights at a 45° angle but the problem is their light is sharp on the drawing — it's uneven. Is it possible to make it better — or is it not easy to use these torches as lights for photography?

Also, if I hold the torches in hand, instead of fixing them somewhere, would the shake of light make quality of photo bad?

EDIT: Some people are always ready to mark questions duplicate. I don't have enough budget to buy Polarizer or anything else. All other things discussed there I know. I just want to know can I use torch for that case, and how to make it even.

Comment: Take the picture outdoors on a cloudy day.

Comment: If you are only doing a few, outdoors on a cloudy day like xenoid says will work good. If you are doing this all the time, buy some cheap speedlights and cheap RF remotes (like Yongnuo). Put them at 45 degrees.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the best practices for taking pictures of a canvas?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/what-are-the-best-practices-for-taking-pictures-of-a-canvas)

Comment: This reads like an X→Y problem. Is the real issue finding a way to cheaply light artwork evenly?

Comment: @MichaelC yes, if not perfect, but still better than my current situation (my room has not enough light)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Frame Challenge Answer:** On cloudy days, just go outside. On sunny days, go under a patio or use a thin white sheet over a large window. Alternatively, you can build a *scrim* using PVC pipe and anything that will diffuse the light (sheets work well. I've built one using a more industrial version of parchment/wax paper as well).

**How to properly use 2 household torches for taking Photo indoor?:** Use the same principals as above - put something thin in front of the torch to diffuse the light. However, two torches will be such little light that you'll need to use a tripod and a very long exposure to not end up having to crank the ISO. Alternatively, experiment with light-painting (though, this probably won't work well as you'll end up having a "streaky" image. This technique is not normally used to light artwork but is instead used to create interesting images).

**Don't be cheap answer:** Yongnuo makes some cheap speed lights that could be used, or you could try to find a used speed light in good condition. Bouncing these off of the ceiling/wall will work well to diffuse the light. Studio Strobes can also often be found used, or an entry level AlienBee400 or similar could also be acquired fairly cheaply (in the grand scheme of things).

Comment: I'd like to add that [*diffusion*](https://digital-photography-school.com/three-types-light-diffused-backlight-reflected-use/) is key in this answer. OP, you want an equal distribution of light over your drawing, that is why clouded days are often great for portrait photography: soft light on the face, instead of harsh shadows.