# I need some free panorama stitching software

Tags: software, panorama, macintosh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools are good for creating panoramas/stitching multiple photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/230/which-tools-are-good-for-creating-panoramas-stitching-multiple-photos)

I have iPad and a Mac. The software could be for either, but I really need it to be free or very cheap. Trial versions are acceptable, as long as they leave no watermark.
Any recommendations?