# What is a good 360 degree camera?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, sony, 360-panorama

I want to buy a new camera for a 360 degree shoot , so can anyone suggest me the good one

I have seen that Sony Bloggie camera which has 3D camera and a 360 degree lens too, so does this camera have good quality to take 360 photos?

[Link to Sony Bloggie Camera](http://store.sony.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10551&storeId=10151&langId=-1&productId=8198552921666294217#specifications)

Comment: As this may be a duplicate of existing questions: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/230/which-tools-are-good-for-creating-panoramas-stitching-multiple-photos and http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/495/what-is-the-best-shoot-trick-plus-software-to-take-360-photos I instead answered the specific question about the Sony Bloggie camera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I have read, the **Sony Bloggie has quite poor quality and is pretty limited as far as what you can do for 360 degree photography**. It is more of a market gimmick then a full fledged option. The camera only starts with a 5MP sensor, and stretching that out over a very small sensor, and a very very large aspect, you can only imagine that it isn't setup for serious use.

Some opinions from reviews:

- The 360 degree attachment is great as a novelty item but you won't want to take serious video with it([link](http://www.amazon.com/review/R2ZJZ4CLDXM503/ref=cm_cr_dp_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B0043CYRIW&nodeID=502394&tag=&linkCode=)).
- While 360 degree mode is more a toy than premium class, you get good casual takes. Funny mode to play with. ([link](http://www.amazon.com/review/R1Z0PKP1V5A1JU/ref=cm_cr_pr_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B0043CYRIW&nodeID=&tag=&linkCode=)).

You might want to take a look at [pano-pro](http://www.pano-pro.com) if you want to get into this field.

I found a pano photography forum that has greater expert advice on using this camera in the real world here: [Link](http://www.panoguide.com/forums/qna/9177/)

Answer (score 2):

You can't expect good quality from an in-camera panorama mode. A lot of cameras in the price range of the one you posted have a "panorama-assist" or "stitch-assist" mode, which I think is better. In this mode you take the first picture and then for each successive picture you get an overlay in the LCD that shows you how much you need to rotate to take the next picture and get a decent overlap to help in the stitching.

There are cameras of all brands with the pano-assist mode. I am a Canon fan, and I can recommend the Canon SX230 HS (at this price range, there are better and more expensive models as well). Each picture you take with this camera is 12MP, so the stitch  panorama will have a really nice resolution. The DVD included with the camera has a stitching software to create cylindrical 360 degrees panoramas from the individual pictures. And of course you can always get [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) if you need more control over the stitching process.

Keep in mind that if you are after fully spherical panos (i.e 360 horizontal by 180 vertical), then doing that with cameras in this price range is possible but very hard, as you will need to shoot several rows to cover the 180 degree vertical range.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research, I bought this camera (a Bloggie) last week and so far it has lived up to my expectations.

Sony bought the company of Bloggie because of the simple camera with such a success.
Before I had a cheap small Canon camera (without a prisma) what made perfect photos and could be used to take 360 degree with Stich-panorama.

I bought the Bloggie mainly because of its 3D and because the high 'good quality' with full HD video, both of which are new for me.

I'm a semi-professional photographer and spend almost as much time looking through my camera than my eyes. Its small size makes the Bloggie very portable which means less missed shots.  For me, it gives better quality than a middle class (Sony) DSLR camera.

It's written above about the limited Bloggie cameras and it has had availability issues as a result of the high level of the water in Thailand and nearby regions.

I bought mine after Sony Netherlands sent me a newsletter from their Outlet products and last week the price of the Bloggie was 119 Euro incl. 2-year guarantee and a small USB cable and a charming packing, a small box (like a jewelery-packing)

There is another Bloggie model type: MHS-FS3K without 3D which can make 360 degrees photos, but you need to buy a separate lens which can make that kind of photos. Even with that lens you cannot zoom in/out or film with the splendid LED-light (max. 5 meter).

You can read more about the Bloggie in the [Sony Manual English (old model) but the same](http://www.docs.sony.com/release/MHSTSseries_handbook.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify in your original question if you need digital or not. Whilst I think you most likely do, I'm going to suggest the following film alternative:

A while back I saw an episode of the Gadget Show where they demonstrated the [Lomography Spinner 360](http://uk.shop.lomography.com/spinner-360)

It's a very simple concept, and takes a standard 35mm film canister.  You hold it up, pull the string and it spins round propelled by nothing more than a rubber band (I think).  You can get up to 8 exposures on a standard 36-shot roll of film, and being standard film - it can be developed anywhere.

Looked like a lot of fun, and you'd definitely get some interesting shots with it!

Answer (score 0):

Might want to check out Panono. It takes 108 MP spherical photos with zero blind spots. ([source](http://www.slant.co/topics/2124/viewpoints/3/~what-are-the-best-360-degree-cameras~panono-panoramic-ball-camera))