# Capturing and stitching images without distortion/perspective correction given perfect control

Tags: photo-editing, composition, theory

I'm working with a virtual scene and camera. Unfortunately, the program locks the render resolution at 1920x1080 with no direct workarounds. This is significantly lower than I'd like.

Given the ability to measure and adjust camera position, rotation, and focal length/FOV with perfect precision and accuracy, **could a series of images be taken and stitched into a single higher resolution image without the need for distortion/perspective correction?**

I'm aware of [this post](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/230/which-tools-are-good-for-creating-panoramas-stitching-multiple-photos) about stitching together panoramas, but I thought given the unique benefits of my situation, it warrented it's own post.

Comment: I don't see where your situation differs from a "normal" panorama? You can position your virtual camera, take a series of overlapping images an stitch them. If I understood correctly and you are working in a 3d environment, this pictures will need perspective correction as well. Those corrections are not necessary because of imperfections of camera lenses, but becaus every picture (projection of a 3d world onto a plane) will have distortion; the bigger the FOV, the more!

Comment: Is this a photography question? It sounds like you're talking about 3D computer graphics when you say "rendering". Is that the case?

Comment: @smow Gotcha, I just wasn't sure if my ability to adjust things perfectly lent me anything extra.

Comment: @scottbb It's 3D graphics, but the principals are no different than the real world. The constraints imposed are the same.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about computer rendering in a context that has no relevance to photography.

Comment: @mattdm It seems pretty relevant to photography to me. Though I *personally* am working in a virtual environment, the concepts apply to real-world photography as well. Look at the answer: use a shift lens, the same as architectural photography. Think about the 3D environment as no more than a "photography simulator."

Comment: @JMY1000, however, you're rejecting the Q&A we already have in place for general photographic panostitching because it doesn't apply to your special CG case. Have you considered using [Blender](https://www.blender.org/), which _doesn't_ lock output resolution to 1920x1080? There's [an entire SE community](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) for it.

Comment: @inkista I'm very familiar with Blender: if you take a look at my SE profile, you'll notice I've posted on the Blender SE before. However, for my use case, I currently need to use IFM (a fork of SFM.) No SE exists for that AFAIK.

Comment: @inkista I'd also argue that the use case *can* apply in the real world as well, such as needing no distortion but having the ability to set up dollies and such, or needing to create a large image from a set point such as a tripod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible using FOV and camera rotation alone. You need to setup an [oblique frustum](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ObliqueFrustum.html), which is equivalent of the [shift lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilt%E2%80%93shift_photography#Shift), used in architectural photography.